# SwiftUI trying to pass a var to ButtonStyle

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm to pass a custom value to set a button style font size.  I tried to pass the vale to the struct but can't get the func part to see the value I passed.  This my be very basic, but I new to xcode and have been trying to find a solution to what I'm doing wrong.

**This work:**

```
Button(action: {
    bleManager.writeOutgoingValue(data: "sky")
}) {
    Text("Sky")
}
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.white, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
.foregroundColor(.black)
.buttonStyle(LightButtonStyle())
.cornerRadius(5)


struct LightButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var height: CGFloat = 40
    var width: CGFloat = 140
    var textSidePadding: CGFloat = 4
    var fontSize: CGFloat = 20
    var weight: Font.Weight = .semibold
    var disabled: Bool = false

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], textSidePadding)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 3 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: configuration.isPressed)
            .font(.system(size: fontSize, weight: weight, design: .default))
            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
Button(action: {
    bleManager.writeOutgoingValue(data: "sky")
}) {
    Text("Sky")
}
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.white, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
.foregroundColor(.black)
.buttonStyle(LightButtonStyle1(fontSize: customFontSize.large))
.cornerRadius(5)

struct LightButtonStyle1: ButtonStyle {
    var height: CGFloat = 40
    var width: CGFloat = 140
    var textSidePadding: CGFloat = 4
    var weight: Font.Weight = .semibold
    var disabled: Bool = false
    init(fontSize:CGFloat){
        @State() var fontVal: CGFloat = fontSize
    }
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], textSidePadding)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 3 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: configuration.isPressed)
            .font(.system(size: fontVal: $fontVal, weight: weight, design: .default))
            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
```

However I get: Cannot find 'fontVal' in scope

I tried moving the value in the function, tried using let, tried find an example on goggle.

I just tried:

```
struct LightButtonStyle1: ButtonStyle {
    var height: CGFloat = 40
    var width: CGFloat = 140
    var textSidePadding: CGFloat = 4
    var weight: Font.Weight = .semibold
    var disabled: Bool = false
    init(fontSize:CGFloat){
         var fontVal: CGFloat = fontSize
     }
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], textSidePadding)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 3 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: configuration.isPressed)
            .font(.system(size: fontVal: fontVal, weight: weight, design: .default))
            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
```

The Init is getting:
variable 'fontVal' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it

The func is getting:
Cannot find 'fontVal' in scope

Comment: `@State()` isn't valid Swift syntax. Declare `fontVal` just like you did `height`, `weight`, `textSidePadding`, etc

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I did that and I got: "Variable 'fontVal' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it". I'm trying to get fontVal into the func makeBody, and thank you for any help.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the attempt. Remember to use `$fontVal` _without_ the `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fontVal` should be declared at the top level of your struct, like the other properties.

Then, you *set* that value in the `init`.

Finally, you have an extra `fontVal` in your `makeBody`

```
struct LightButtonStyle1: ButtonStyle {
    var height: CGFloat = 40
    var width: CGFloat = 140
    var textSidePadding: CGFloat = 4
    var weight: Font.Weight = .semibold
    var disabled: Bool = false
    var fontVal: CGFloat // <-- Here
    init(fontSize:CGFloat){
        self.fontVal = fontSize // <-- Here
     }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], textSidePadding)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 3 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: configuration.isPressed)
            .font(.system(size: fontVal, weight: weight, design: .default))  // <-- Here
            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, that worked great, I have been programming PHP for years and xcode/swift syntax is new, I see I have a lot to learn.  Once again thank you!